# How to set up crontab permissions to be readable by apache

Tags: apache, unix, cron

I have a django application which should read and write to a crontab. However if I create the file with this:

```
sudo su www-data
crontab -e
```

I can see that:

```
# ls -la
total 12
drwx-wx--T 2 root     crontab 4096 Aug 13 16:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root    4096 May  1  2012 ..
-rw------- 1 www-data crontab  202 Aug 13 16:28 www-data
```

However the file is still not readable and writeable by django. If I switch with `sudo` to `www-data` user I can't edit the file. How to setup the permissions properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to read that dir, for good reason.

You can however:

1. Read the file with `crontab -l`
2. Replace the crontab with `crontab /path/to/file/which/will/replace/it`.

So a workable solution would be:

1. Store current `crontab -l` in some tempfile.
2. Do you modifications on that tempfile
3. Install that tempfile with `crontab /path/to/tempfile`

The reason is in `man cron`:

> Users are not allowed to edit the files under  that  directory
>          directly  to  ensure that only users allowed by the system to run periodic tasks can add them, and only syntactically correct crontabs will be written
>          there.  This is enforced by having the directory writable only by the crontab group and configuring crontab command with the setgid bid set  for  that
>          specific group.